# работа с клавиатурой с++

Tags: c++, клавиатура

есть какие-то библиотеки для клавиатуры )
пишу игру(тетрис) в sfml там насколько я понял функции предназначены скорее не для регистрации нажатия на клавишу, а для регистрации зажата она или нет
и что-то никак не выходит нормально настроить управление
windows
приложение не консольное

Comment: Допишите в вопрос ОС и консольное или GUI-приложение у вас.

Comment: не консольное) виндовс

Comment: @Alexandr, просмотрел API sfml — вполне подходит для «регистрации нажатия на клавишу», что именно смущает?... а любое системно-зависимое решение здесь, говоря ковбойским языком, будет смотреться как седло на корове...